# Таймер срабатывает раньше времени или вообще не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

При создании записи, создаётся заметка со следующими свойствами:

- номер заметки isbn
- статус заметки
- дата
- время

Вычисляется время в миллисекундах и передаётся таймеру `setTimeout`, по истечении времени изменяется статус заметки с `Inprocess` на `Failed`.

Не могу понять, почему для некоторых дат, таймер срабатывает сразу или не срабатывает вообще.

Например, если срок равен 30 августа, то таймер сработает сразу, а не 30 августа, от настоящего времени.

Так же он не срабатывает если задать прошедшую дату, например 1 июля, статус заметки будет в процессе, а не failed https://repl.it/Jt3i/4

Comment: Что именно вводится в поле с датой, когда таймер срабатывает неправильно?

Comment: @Zergatul, Строка

Comment: я понимаю, но какое именно значение?

Comment: @Zergatul, К примеру, дата 30.08.2017 и время 10:00.

Comment: В каком браузере смотрите? Internet Explorer и Safari?

Comment: @AlexanderBragin, Только Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл ошибку и она была не связанна с вычислениями. Дело в том, что время ожидания метода 'setTimeout' имеет лимит, который равен 2147483647 миллисекунд. Моя дата конвертированная в миллисекунды была больше этого значения. Поэтому метод setTimeout срабатывал сразу же.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `createAllDate` ожидает дату начиная с года, типа 2017-08-30, но вы передаете в неправильном формате.

```
  createAllDate( formElDeadline, formElTime ) {
     var allDate = formElDeadline,
           years = allDate.slice(0,4),
           months = allDate.slice(5,7),
         days = allDate.slice(8),
           times = formElTime,
           hours = times.slice(0,2),
           minutes = times.slice(3);
```

Comment: только что проверил, извлёк из формы значение, которое равно 2017-08-30, так что всё передаётся правильно.

Comment: не могли бы вы уточнить, что именно неправильного в формате даты?

Comment: Что значит "извлёк значение из формы"? Вы привели выше в комментарии пример неправильной даты, я ее подставил и посмотрел что делает код, и увидел что она парсится неправильно.

Comment: Я выбрал дату в iput date за 30 августа 2017 года. Дальше извлёк value (её) и передеал для отображения в консоле, где значение было 2017-08-30.

Comment: Я смотрел в Firefox раньше. Только что попробовал в хроме, у меня все правильно сработало. `Task.js`, строка 45, `timeForTimer = 2394780000`. Посмотрите, в дебаге, что у вас, когда неправильно срабатывает.

Comment: Я всё просмотрел, каждое значение (день, месяц, год, час, минуты) выводил в консоле  и отдельно переводил в миллисекунды на калькуляторе. Вся дата и время конвертируется в миллисекунды корректно, но я до сих пор продолжаю не понимать в чём загвозка.